# How to change to Year-Month-Day format in R

Tags: r, date

My data look like this:  `"19970325" "19970325" "19970422" "19970516"`

I want to convert to: `1997-03-25, 1977-03-25, 1997-04-22....`

I found 
`df[,2] <- format(df[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d")` but it's doesn't work well.

```
    date    Amount
1   4   19970101    29.33
2   4   19970118    29.73
3   4   19970802    14.96
4   4   19971212    26.48
5   21  19970101    63.34
6   21  19970113    11.77
7   50  19970101    6.79
8   71  19970101    13.97
9   86  19970101    23.94
10  111 19970101    35.99
11  111 19970111    32.99
12  111 19970315    77.96
13  111 19970416    59.30
14  111 19970424    134.98
```

Comment: Try `v1 <-  c("19970325", "19970325", "19970422", "19970516"); as.Date(v1, '%Y%m%d')`

Comment: Error: unexpected numeric constant in "df[,2] <- as.Date(as.character(df[,2]1"

Comment: As per the example provided I am not getting any errors.

Comment: I try to convert column from table (i used CDNOW_sample)

Comment: I don't know what `CDNOW_sample` is.  Please update your post with small example using the output of `dput` ie. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`

Comment: How to remove duplicated ID?

Comment: Your comment about removing duplicated IDs is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `lubridate` (`install.library("lubridate")`)

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("20110604")

## [1] "2011-06-04 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 as.Date(as.character(df1$date), format='%Y%m%d')
 #[1] "1997-01-01" "1997-01-18" "1997-08-02" "1997-12-12" "1997-01-01"
 #[6] "1997-01-13" "1997-01-01" "1997-01-01" "1997-01-01" "1997-01-01"
 #[11] "1997-01-11" "1997-03-15" "1997-04-16" "1997-04-24"
```

#### Update

If you need to remove the duplicated IDs, one option is `duplicated`.  The below code gives the first row of each duplicated ID.

```
 df1[!duplicated(df1$id),]
 #    id     date Amount
 #1    4 19970101  29.33
 #5   21 19970101  63.34
 #7   50 19970101   6.79
 #8   71 19970101  13.97
 #9   86 19970101  23.94
 #10 111 19970101  35.99
```

Suppose, if you need to get the sum of 'Amount' per id, use one of the aggregate by group functions.

```
  aggregate(Amount~id, df1, sum)
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(id = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 21L, 21L, 50L, 71L, 86L, 
 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L), date = c(19970101L, 19970118L, 
 19970802L, 19971212L, 19970101L, 19970113L, 19970101L, 19970101L, 
 19970101L, 19970101L, 19970111L, 19970315L, 19970416L, 19970424L
 ), Amount = c(29.33, 29.73, 14.96, 26.48, 63.34, 11.77, 6.79, 
 13.97, 23.94, 35.99, 32.99, 77.96, 59.3, 134.98)), .Names = c("id", 
 "date", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
 "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))
```